# Selenium selecting different filtered search results

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

website is marinetraffic.com

example of search results below, first search result returned is not appropriate, however the 2nd and 4th results are.

[image]

What identifies these results is within div class jss90 and jss89 respectively shown below

[image]

using something like below returns nothing however

```
browser.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//div[contains(@class, 'jss90')]")
```

Aim in this example is to find search results that match ATLANTICA between jss90 tags and contains Bulk Carrier between jss89 tags, append each match to a list then .click() the first one in the list

Answer (score 0):

If content is dinamically generated on the client side, then you might need to add some delay to allow the page enough time to load the elements you want to scrape.

Take a look here for multiple methods to introduce delays in your selenium scraper:
https://www.browserstack.com/guide/selenium-wait-for-page-to-load